# ASCII key encoding in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, encoding

I am new to PHP and my first assignment. The secretword is encrypted using c# (TripleDES /

CBC). On comparison, I found that the IV, and the secretword bytes do match, but not the key.

This is the c# code that works fine...

```
   string epws = secretWord;
   byte[] rawdata = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(char[] aArr);
   mCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

   string key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(rawdata);
   key = key.Substring(0, 24); 
   mCryptoService.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

   byte[] ivB = new byte[8];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(rawdata, 31, ivB, 0, 8);
   mCryptoService.IV = ivB;

   byte[] epwb = Convert.FromBase64String(epws);
   ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = mCryptoService.CreateDecryptor();
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(epwb, 0, epwb.Length);
   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs);
   return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This is the PHP code that I need help...

```
<?php

 // dkey is the rawdata passed in as string from database

 $byteArray = unpack('C*', $dkey);
 $mkey = implode(array_map('chr', $byteArray));
 $mkey = base64_decode($mkey);

 $iv = substr($mkey, 31, 8);
 $mkey = substr($mkey, 0, 24);

 // the encrypted secretword passed in as string from database
 $epws = base64_decode($epws);

 $ok= trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $mkey, $epws, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

?>
```

These are the keys that are different. IF I substitute the c# key in php, it works fine.

```
From c#
key = (35, 63, 63,43, 63,49,20, 63, 63,97,21,24, 63,97, 63, 63,125,98,125,15,62,108,55,70)

From php            
key = (35,229,239,43,244,49,20,141,144,97,21,24,200,97,196,216,125,98,125,15,62,108,55,70)
           ^   ^      ^         ^   ^            ^      ^   ^
```

Don't know what else to do.

Comment: When I see `$ok= trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $mkey, $epw, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));` I wonder if `$epw` is incorrect, should it be `$epws`?

Comment: Your are right. I had made the change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key consists of bytes, not characters. If you need a key displayed as string - usually you don't - then you should encode it to hexadecimals. If you want to use it later on, you can decode the hexadecimals to a byte array again.

ASCII only has values from 0 to 127, of which the bottom 32 characters as well as the value 127 isn't printable. So your C# code is in that sense worse than your PHP code, and it needs the biggest change.

---

Currently the C# code is simply replacing bytes outside the ASCII range (0-127) with question marks (`3F` hex, or 63 in decimals - check the print out of the key). You can simply replace each value of 128 or higher with the value 63.

Obviously that means that your key loses entropy, *on average* it will only be half as strong (true in your example, with 8 bytes replaced). If you are unlucky then *all* bytes are converted into question marks (about once in 65536) or anything in between, leaving you extremely vulnerable to attack.

Comment: I don't have much say on the c# code. My focus is on the PHP side to get working. Thanks.

Comment: @prav You shouldn't just follow any spec without comment, prav. The person giving the assignment should first get a clue about what cryptography actually is before trying to teach others. Amended answer anyway.

Comment: You are right. I did check the print out of the key and as you said it had the question marks. So the only thing I can do in PHP code is to replace the value. Also, thanks for your advice.